# prevent child tables from being populated in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Apologies if this has been posted elsewhere but I can't seem to find any info regarding this.

I'm trying to load an object using the LinqtoSql data context.

I have a `Page` and `Template` table. There is a relation between the two:

`Page.TemplateId` to `Template.TemplateID`

The data context autocreated the `Page` and `Template` classes.

My code is:

```
public class PageRepository
{
    Table<Page> _table = (new HospoEngineDataContext()).GetTable<Page>();

    public IQueryable<Page> Pages
    {
        get { return _table; }
    }

    public Page GetPageByName(string name)
    {
        Page page = (from p in _table where p.Name == name select p).FirstOrDefault();

        return page;
    }
}
```

When I run `GetPageByName()`, it'll populate the returned `Page` object fine.

However it seems it also loads the `Page.Template` sub object too.

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?

EDIT:
I've just installed SqlServerQueryVisualizer and created a new query so I can see what sql is being generated by adding this code to the above class:

```
public IQueryable<Page> Test()
    {
        var pages = (from p in _context.Pages where p.Name == "Home Page Name" select p);

        return pages;

    }
```

It turns out that the sql being generated is:

```
{SELECT [t0].[PageId], [t0].[TemplateId], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Title], [t1].[TemplateId] AS [TemplateId2], [t1].[Name] AS [Name2], [t1].[TemplateFile]
FROM [dbo].[Pages] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Templates] AS [t1] ON [t1].[TemplateId] = [t0].[TemplateId]
WHERE [t0].[Name] = @p0
}
```

Which doesn't seem to be only loading the `Pages` table.

Comment: @sf re your edit: look at the info I posted on my answer. Either there is code explicitly setting eager load after the _context instance is created or the model is configured in the designer to not delay load Template.

Comment: i just did a trace and it's not showing the join.

Thanks muchly :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very likely that it isn't.

It surely gets populated when you check that property - either in code or in the debugger (if that's what you are doing).

There are some properties involved that could cause it, but I would discard what I say above first (attach a profiler to your database).

If it isn't the above, check the DelayLoaded property & also make sure the DataLoad options of the datacontext aren't being explicitely set to eager load Template.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Linq-to-Sql uses *deferred execution*. This means that the `Page.Template` object doesn't get loaded until you access it for the first time, though it looks like it's immediately loaded. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399393.aspx) explains this well. Notice that, if you are debugging with visual studio, when you open the `Template` property on `Page`, it will get loaded just then.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.
I was doing a check to see if the Page.Template object was null however it wasn't. 
It became a little confusing at that point.

Comment: I just did a test of this and noted my observations in the edit above.

It looks like the Template table is being load. Unless there is some strange quantum observer reaction happening whereby when i peek at this code, the table gets loaded.

cheers for your help btw

Answer (score 1):

I am reasonablly sure (attach a profiler to your database to confirm) that LINQtoSQL will populate the object on demand. If you don't query the child object, it wont populate.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the template member in the Linq to Sql designer surface, then change the property DelayLoaded to true.  You could validate that it works correctly by watching the code execute from SQL Profiler